# Cordova app shows default icon on iOS 7 AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, app-store

An iPhone app built with Cordova shows default icon on AppStore on iOS 7. I changed all the icons in Xcode, and submitted to the AppStore again, but still it shows the default icon. Below are the screenshots of Xcode and AppStore on iPhone running iOS7. All other icons work fine.

Cordova version is `3.5.0-0.2.4`

[image]

[image]